# sql запрос добавление второй таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Написать запрос по w3schools.com
Вывести все продукты, у которых код продукта >= 64 или продукты, у которых поставщик = "Tokyo Traders" (подзапрос).
Помогите начало понял
SELECT ProductName FROM [Products]
WHERE ProductID >=64
а как к нему добавить еще вторую таблицу(продукты, у которых поставщик = "Tokyo Traders")?
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all
Спасибо зарание!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

написано же - с помощью подзапроса

```
AND supplier_id = (select id form suppliers where name = 'xxx')
```